# MS ADAL Ionic Cordova Plugin

Tags: cordova, azure, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-2017, ionic3

I want to use [Azure Active Directory Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) for Authentication in one of my ionic 3 app. 
I added the plugin using the following command: 
**ionic cordova-plugin-ms-adal --save**

After adding windows platform and targeting window 10 using preferences in config.xml file, I run build command for windows as follows:

**ionic Cordova build windows**

and imported the project in visual studio 2017.

When I run the project its giving me the following error:

**Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 MyProjectName  1**
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, so after searching a little bit about this issue, I found the solution that Whenever you want to use [MS ADAL For Cordova](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) in your ionic or cordova project , use this command to remove the plugin : 
**cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ms-adal --save**

and add the plugin by running the following command:

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-adal@0.8.x --save**

By the time of writing this answer, if you don't use **@0.8.x** in your command, it will work fine for **android** and **ios** but when you want to build your **windows** project, it will give you some errors like above.

Hope it will resolve your issue. 
Thanks

Comment: i m also using this plugin. can you help how to get authencationcontext? can you explain. I don't know about active directive.